# How to start/approach the Scorchers DLC?

Tags: rage

Scorchers DLC for RAGE has just been released and I am planning to buy it and take the chance to finish the game.

My last savegame was immediatly after "The Big Boss" fight. Are the new DLC mission before or after that mission? Can I use my existing savegame to play the new contents added with this DLC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new Scorchers DLC gives you access to a variety of new areas and quest chains. There is [a post over at the Bethesda forums which shows how to start the new DLC content](http://forums.bethsoft.com/topic/1431690-getting-started-with-the-scorchers/):

- To begin the new quests, you'll first need to complete the Ghost Hideout mission for the Hagar Settlement. After finishing the first Main Story Mission, you’ll be able to take on the optional DLC quest
- If you've already left the Hagar Settlement, or are further in the game, you will instantly gain the quest information, pointing you toward a new cave in the starting zone of Rage
- If your save happens to be in Capital Prime, you will be able to finish the area, then load into the Eastern Wasteland. From there you can journey back to the first Wasteland and reach the caves near the Hagar settlement